# What is "Supply Input for Analog Functions" on a buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Regarding [this datasheet](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2253EQI-30.pdf) for a DC Buck Converter, there is a VCC pin that on pg-2 shows an arrow pointing "out". What is this "out" connection arrow used for in practice?

Further along on the datasheet (pg-12), they show a board layout with that pin connected to GND via a capacitor. Is that a viable way to connect this converter if I don't have a use for whatever that "out" arrow is for?

Comment: I think they mixed up analog GND and power GND there.

Comment: Sometimes PMICs (e.g. buck converters) have a voltage that they generate in order to power up their inner circuitry. They get that voltage out, if they need a holdup capacitor to maintain that voltage. 

But this case seems different, I guess that they threw a LDO in for noise sensitive analog circuitry. Because the datasheet talks about a low dropout linear regulator for the Vcc pin.

Comment: Add the capacitor, though. But it is okay if you don't use the voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this "out" connection arrow used for in practice?

It's on the first page: "The AOZ2253EQI-30 integrates an internal linear
regulator to generate 5.3V VCC from input."

It means that they make some regulated power available with all the advantages and disadvantages of a LDO linear regulator.

I can't speak for anyone else, but if I used it at all, it would be for some low current consumption circuit that needed to come up before the switching regulator did.

> Is that a viable way to connect this converter if I dont have a use for whatever that "out" arrow is for?

It's certainly what they call out.  You *do* need the cap, according to the datasheet -- LDO regulators, particularly those of a certain vintage, tend to need them.

Answer (score 2):

The VCC pin is an output from the internal linear LDO regulator. The supply is used internally by the chip functions, in general it is not meant to be used externally and the datasheet does not mention how much current could be used externally so officially, it can't be used externally. The output of any LDO still needs a capacitor, so the only function here is to provide the capacitor externally for the internal LDO regulator, nothing else.

And the datasheet ia clear on this; the capacitor on VCC pin is mandatory for stable operation, it can not be omitted, even if you don't use it externally, the chip does use it internally.

Answer (score 0):

The Yellow copper pad area "Vout" on p12 is the MAIN output of this chip.

- on the left is feedback input from Vout and the layout is critical to keep tight.

If you do not need Vout, all that is left is the 5.3Vcc LDO output which is a waste if that is all you use.